# Which movie features the least (non-zero) screen time on/of Earth?

Tags: history-of, real-location

**Preamble:**
I was watching *Guardian of the Galaxy Vol. 2* and there were a few scenes when Ego is gaining strength and the material goo he left behind on many planets starts expanding like crazy.   So there are shots of many planets, and Earth is one among them.   However, obviously most of the movie takes place nowhere near Earth.   So this got me thinking about in which movie Earth plays the smallest role (but not none).

Now, clearly *GOTG2* is not the answer scene it contains flashback scenes as well.    I went and checked the original *Guardains of the Galaxy*, and it contains around 3 minutes and 25 seconds of flashback at the beginning.   So...

**Question:**

In which film are there some shots of or on Earth, but they are exceedingly short?   Which film has the shortest duration?

For the purpose of this question, shots of Earth, on Earth, etc all count.  We will count the atmosphere and orbit of Earth as well.

Actually, I'd like to take a relative sort of view of what counts as *here*, for example:

- Earth itself would count for a film that takes place primarily in Earth orbit.
- Earth, Earth orbit, and the moon would all count for a film that take place primarily on other planets in the solar system.
- Anywhere in our solar system would count for a film that takes place primarily around another star
- etc.

But that is getting pretty complicated, so I'm hoping the best answer is free of ambiguity and I won't clarify unless it should become necessary.

Something out there has merely a few seconds of our home, right?

Comment: If you extend to TV shows and proportionate time then how about Farscspe, Blake's 7 and various Star Trek series.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie Battlestar Galactica is another good example.

Comment: Wow.  Remote bandwagon much?   Explanation anyone?   Also, to the VTCers, how is this too broad or unclear?  It's not, or please leave a comment.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie, if you bring up TV, that's a different question.

Comment: I VTCed as Too Broad when the question was only a few minutes old, then about 10 minutes later came back and removed it when I re-read the question and realized I missed the requirement that the Earth is shown at least once.  If that requirement wasn't there, then Too Broad definitely applies; there's plenty where it doesn't show up at all, even with your gradually-widening "what is _here_" examples.

Comment: @Izkata, well, that would a monumentally stupid question.  :)     I wonder if some of the downvotes are for that (mis)interpretation.

Comment: I don't take stopwatches with me when I go see movies, so I can't say for sure, but someone might have to time the opening scene of _City of a Thousand Planets_.

Answer (score 4):

Alien Resurrection could be close if i remember it right. It's a long time since i saw it but iirc there is a quick glimpse of earth right at the end. I don't remember earth based bits earlier on. I will check details and try to update with a clip later.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about a movie involving a space travel disrupted by an alien threat with a single shot of the Earth as the ship's destination as the final twist, but was wondering which damn movie it was while scrolling. Wasn't it the first Alien ?